# Workaround for let keyword?

Tags: javascript, let

How can I get this

```
var i = 0;
var codes = [1, 2, 3];

for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; ++i)
{
    setTimeout(function(){alert(codes[i]);},100);
}
```

To `alert` `1`, `2` and `3` without using `let` keyword?

or bind an event on an element (**[example](http://jsfiddle.net/QyvNK/)**):

```
var i = 0;
var codes = [1, 2, 3];

for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; ++i)
{
    $("div").eq(i).click(function(){
        alert( codes[i] );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a self-executing anonymous function and pass in `i` as an argument for variable closure.

```
var i = 0;
var codes = [1, 2, 3];

for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; ++i)
{
    (function( index ) {
        setTimeout(function(){alert(codes[index]);},100);
    })(i);
}
```

[Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/5PGJx/)

Comment: That would cause all 3 to go off simultaneously, is that the desired functionality?

Comment: If not, he can change the delay on the setTimeout to `100*(index+1)`

Answer (score 3):

You need to make use of a closure.  I typically create a "generator" function that returns a function which is defined in the desired context:

```
var i = 0;
var codes = [1, 2, 3];
function callbackGenerator(i) { 
   return function(){alert(codes[i]);}
}

for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; ++i)
{
    setTimeout(callbackGenerator(i), 100);
}
```

More info and good examples here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = 0;
var codes = [1, 2, 3];

var timeoutFunc = function() {
    alert(codes[i++]);
    if (i < codes.length) {
        setTimeout(timeoutFunc, 100);
    }
};

setTimeout(timeoutFunc, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
var codes = [1, 2, 3];

for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; ++i)
    setTimeout(function(code){return function(){
        alert(code);
    }}(codes[i]), 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [self-executing function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript):

```
for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; ++i) (function(bound_i) {
    setTimeout(function(){alert(codes[bound_i]);},100);
})(i);
```

Optionally using a `var` statement for more verbose code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; ++i) (function() {
    var bound_i = i;
    setTimeout(function(){alert(codes[bound_i]);},100);
})();
```

Or use a named function instead if you want to:

```
function foo(i) {
    setTimeout(function(){alert(codes[i]);},100);
}

for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; ++i) {
    foo(i);
}
```

Either example forms a closure, which introduces new variable scope. Alternatively, ES5 has [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) that could be used on the anonymous function, but it is not universally supported in all browsers yet. (I'm thinking of IE.)